# AWS Elastic Transcoding - Batch Processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, batch-processing, amazon-elastic-transcoder

Is there a way to Batch Transcode 1 file in S3 to multiple versions and a thumbnail in a single API call?

Right now I need to call 2 jobs and manage the Job ID and check it back later. What I want to achieve is create a job which converts the Video to MP$ - 720/480 and a thumbnail and once it's completed it will send a notification that the transcoding is complete and I can chance the status from `processing` to `completed` in my database.

Comment: do you mean one job for every video quality?

Comment: @NourdineAlouane 1 job for 2 video quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if I understand your problem correctly, I think you simply need [aws sns](https://aws.amazon.com/en/sns/). Or you can use aws lambda service to detect any new transcoded then uploaded video to your s3 target bucket => then trigger a lambda function to do backend job.

But I think aws transcoder service is pretty much expensive. If you're getting rounded up to the nearest minute, that's a huge cost when your videos are short. otherways you can run you own ffmpeg version inside a dedicated server and use cron jobs for changing video status (that's what I'm using right now)

Don't forget to make the videos available one by one, do not wait until all qualities are available before changing video status to "completed".

Hope it helps

Comment: Can you please provide the code that you have implemented for converting video format using cron?